# How to find the parent of an ASP.NET TreeView node in JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, treeview

How to find the parent of an ASP.NET TreeView node in JavaScript?

Comment: You should accept answers that most helped you resolve the problem by clicking the empty check-mark beside that answer, this helps everyone out: give you rep, gives them rep, makes the answer easier for the next person to find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the element's ClientID, then call `getElementById` and check the `parentNode`, like this: (In a `<script>` block on the page)

```
document.getElementById('<%=myTreeView.ClientID%>').parentNode
```

Comment: What's a `<scipr>` block, is that HTML5? :)